# TS error: Type 'event' is missing the following properties from type 'keyboardevent'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom event listener hook that looks like this:

```
const useEventListener = (
  eventName: string,
  handler: ({key} : KeyboardEvent) => void,
) => {
  const savedHandler = useRef<({key} : KeyboardEvent) => void>(handler)

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler
  }, [handler])

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = (event: KeyboardEvent) => savedHandler.current(event)

    window.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener)
    }
  }, [eventName])
}
```

This is throwing the error,

```
TS error: Type 'event' is missing the following properties from type 'keyboardevent': char, key and 18 others
```

Am I typing the useRef incorrectly? I wasn't able to find anything from [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.documentandelementeventhandlers.html) that work either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: your `eventListener` expects a `KeyboardEvent` but you are using it with the `addEventListener` signature that takes a `string` for the event name, and a listener typed `(e: Event) => void`. There's no guarantee that it will provide you with a `KeyboardEvent` and that is what your listener requires.

Comment: I think `eventName` shouldn't be any `string`, this should be a specific listener string...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's OK.

Working solutions will be

```
const useEventListener = (
    eventName: 'keydown' | 'keyup',
    handler: ({key} : KeyboardEvent) => void,
  ) => {
    const savedHandler = useRef<({key} : KeyboardEvent) => void>(handler)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      savedHandler.current = handler
    }, [handler])
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const eventListener = (event: KeyboardEvent) => savedHandler.current(event)
  
      window.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener);
  
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener)
      }
    }, [eventName])
  }
```

The issue was `eventName: string,`

TS sees that you are allowing to listen for any event (keyboard or not) so it can't guarantee that the emitted event will be **only** keyboard type. So you need to assure TS that you will listen only for keyboard events. This can be done by providing the correct type for the eventName which should be a subset of the keyboard event names.

That's it.

Comment: Ts is awesome if you know how to cook it.